# PHP ImageMagick how to fix child pid 43129 exit signal Abort (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Tags: apache2, php, imagemagick

When I run any ImageMagick processes in PHP, nothing happens for a moment, then the browser shows `The connection was reset` and the Apache error log reports `child pid 43129 exit signal Abort (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`. What do I need to do to get it working again? I'm running Ubuntu Studio 23.10 and Kubuntu desktop with up to date Apache and PHP and this was working until recently.